# How to represent below formula in matlab?

Tags: matlab, formula

I am a beginner in MATLAB, and I need to represent below image, please help me.
[image: formula]

Answer (score 1):

The Matlab documentation website has lots of information on how to answer this question. [Here is a link that describes how the power operator works.](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/25568-defining-functions), otherwise, search the "documentation" or "answers" [area here.](https://www.mathworks.com/support/?s_tid=gn_supp)

The basic answer is to set something called "variables" for each of the variables (x or y), then to use basic matlab operators for the rest.

The general form for an equation would be

```
variablename=variable1*variable2^(3(whatever power or variables))*e^(whatever variables you want)
```

or

```
w=x*(y*z)^(x+y)^2
```

Comment: is this true?? (1-x)^2* exp^(-x^2-(y+1)^2)-(x-x^3-y^3)*exp^(-x^2-y^2);

Comment: yes, but you need to type

   "z= (1-x)^2* exp^(-x^2-(y+1)^2)-(x-x^3-y^3)*exp^(-x^2-y^2);"
and you may or may not need  ";"